# Pages Start From Middle in React Native Material Bottom Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, tabnavigator, bottombar

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am working to build an application with React Native and I am using the React Native Material Bottom Navigation by Timomeh and the Tab Navigator to add Bottom Navigation to my app. However, all the views I add in each tab, seem to start from the middle of the page. I have shared a photo below of how this looks (the red box is the view I want to show but it starts from the middle. I set its width and height to the width and height of the device using Dimensions)  .

[image]

I was wondering if there was a fix for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the flexbox styling for my view and it worked again.